# OData (WCF Data Service) with Subsonic 3

Tags: asp.net, wcf, asp.net-mvc-2, wcf-data-services, odata

I'm trying to use WCF Data Service with Subsonic, but ran into this error when I try to access my "service.svc". I have 2 projects, one is a class library (called "OData") that has Subsonic t4 templates to generate the classes for my table. Another is an ASP.NET MVC2 project that references to the "OData" project.

I then create a new WCF Data Service item inside my ASP.NET MVC project, called "service.svc", points to my "TestDB" context generated by Subsonic that I got from the "OData" project. I've add this attribute on my "service" class per this article: http://theruntime.com/blogs/jaykimble/archive/2008/11/18/quotsubsonicquot-for-services-found-subsonic-3--ado.net-data-services.aspx

This is how my service class looks like:

```
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)] 
public class Service : DataService<SymetraGivingDB>
{
   // This method is called only once to initialize service-wide policies.
   public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
   {
      // TODO: set rules to indicate which entity sets and service operations are visible, updatable, etc.
      // Examples:
      // config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("MyEntityset", EntitySetRights.AllRead);
      // config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("MyServiceOperation", ServiceOperationRights.All);
      config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.AllRead);
      config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("*", ServiceOperationRights.AllRead);
      config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V2;
   }
}
```

When I try to access my http://localhost/Service.svc, I receive this error:

> Request Error
>
> The server encountered an error processing the request.
>   The exception message is 'On data context type
>   'SymetraGivingDB', there is a top
>   IQueryable property 'Users' whose
>   element type is not an entity type.
>   Make sure that the IQueryable property
>   is of entity type or specify the
>   IgnoreProperties attribute on the data
>   context type to ignore this
>   property.'. See server logs for more
>   details. The exception stack trace is:
>
> at System.Data.Services.Providers.ReflectionServiceProvider.PopulateMetadata(IDictionary`2
>   knownTypes, IDictionary`2 childTypes,
>   IDictionary`2 entitySets)
>
>   at System.Data.Services.Providers.BaseServiceProvider.PopulateMetadata()
>
>   at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.CreateProvider()
>   at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.HandleRequest()
>
>   at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.ProcessRequestForMessage(Stream
>   messageBody)
>   at  SyncInvokeProcessRequestForMessage(Object, Object[] , Object[] )
>   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object
>   instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc& rpc)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc& rpc)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc& rpc)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc& rpc)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc& rpc)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean
>   isOperationContextSet)

The error mentions about my "Users" table, which basically has 3 columns: Id / Name / Deleted, there are some relationship between tables, and all my table has "Id" as the Primary key ID.

Any idea why I'm receiving this error?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I just got passed this error by adding a partial class to each entity class: `[DataServiceKey("Id")]`. It seems that it's case-sensitive. But now I have a different error:  
`The exception message is 'The property 'Columns' on type 'OData.Data.User' is not a valid property.`  
This "Columns" was generated by SubSonic, here's the code:  
    public IList<IColumn> Columns{
            get{
                return tbl.Columns;
            }
        }

What do I need to do to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to add [IgnoreProperties("Columns")] attribute on your entity class which will hide the Columns properties from the WCF Data Service runtime. Cause otherwise the runtime doesn't support properties of type IList where T is not an entity type.